# Working with files in MonoGame and Android

Tags: android, monogame

So I made a game in XNA, and to get scores from a file I do something like this...

```
private void GetScore()
    {
        if (File.Exists(scoreFilename))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(scoreFilename))
            {
                hiScore = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Create(scoreFilename);
            fs.Close();
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(scoreFilename))
            {
                sw.Write("0");
            }
            hiScore = 0;
        }
    }
```

This works on Windows, but how would I do this for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [IsolatedStorageFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.aspx). It should work the same as [writing data on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx). Your new code might look something like this:

```
private void GetScore()
{
    var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    if (store.FileExists(scoreFilename))
    {
        var fs = store.OpenFile(scoreFilename, FileMode.Open);
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
        {
            hiScore = Convert.ToInt16(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
    else
    {        
        var fs = store.CreateFile(scoreFilename);            
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
            sw.Write("0");
        }
        hiScore = 0;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, and there's probably a way to do it in less code, but I don't have time to so I've only changed your code the minimum required amount. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: That works, thanks, didn't know about IsolatedStorage, useful thing.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use external directory like this:

Define class to store the context:

```
public class App
{        
    public static Context CurentContext { get; set; }
}
```

On main activity, init the context:

```
public class Activity1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.AndroidGameActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);            

            App.CurentContext = this;

            var g = new Game1();
            SetContentView((View)g.Services.GetService(typeof(View)));
            g.Run();
        }
    }
```

Then do access the external dir:

```
var dirPath = App.CurentContext.GetExternalFilesDir(string.Empty).AbsolutePath;
string filePath = Path.Combine(dirPath, "YourScoreFileName.txt");
using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
{

}
```

And the file should be stored at location like this:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[your_package]/files/
```